# My IPhone 7 is not connecting to the wifi

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

My iPhone 7 is not connecting to my office wifi, but my iPad Mini and Android devices are able to connect.

The problem is only with my office wifi, I am able to connect my home wifi.

Steps I did to resolve the problem:

After entering the credentials, I clicked the trust certificate that is provided by the network. But I am not able to get the router details.

1. I have reset my network settings.
2. I have reset the entire settings.
3. Restored the phone to reset factory settings.
4. Entered details manually.

Nothing helped.

Comment: In Settings > Wi-Fi do you see that network?  If so, when you click the circle i, what information do you see?

Comment: Hey Ajay, welcome to Apple.SE ! I ran into such a situation once and was embarrassed when found out that password was incorrect. Also, can you change your office Wi-Fi account password if possible?

Comment: @GEdgar only IP address and subnet mask. ANd the phone is keep on trying to connect. (loading)

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Password is my work credentials only. So I'm entering only correct password.

Comment: What's the iOS version? There might be something in updates..